# How to use unique array for some type elements?

Tags: typescript, discriminated-union, union-types

I try to make a navigation step where to store current element. Element could be `User {id: string, name: string}, Group {id: string, name: string, blocked: boolean}, Expirience {id: string, years: number}`.

So, navigation could be as:

```
public navigation: User[] | Group[] | Expirience[]
add(entity: User[] | Group[] | Expirience[]) {}
remove(entity: User[] | Group[] | Expirience[]) {}
```

Problem is it is not scalable, tomorrow it could be another type as `Car{id: number, name: string}`. How to unify this?

Important: all of type should contains `id` and `name` to display in navigation

Comment: You want *homogenous* arrays of the same subtype, right? For example `(User | Group)[]` doesn't work for you.

Comment: I need to store any entities as passage history

Comment: OK, in that case, it seems like `type Entity = User | Group | Experience; add(Entity[])` works. You can just adjust `Entity` to add more types to it. Alternatively make it a supertype which `User`, `Group`, and `Experience` extend. Or did I misunderstand something?

Comment: You got this right, but some of entities can have id as number some of them as string. So I can not do supertype, and problem is it looks ugly `User | Group | Experience | ... |.... |...`

Comment: Having a long union type isn't ugly, IMO. In fact, it's much better than having a supertype. It's an ad-hoc supertype in a way but it's much more explicit about what goes in or not. Formatting makes it quite readable by placing each `| NextThing` on new line, too. It does mean you get one long-ish type definition (number of lines = number of members) but you only need it *once*. I suppose your alternative is to do `Entity = {id: string | number}` thus the rest of your types (that have an ID) would structurally fall into it. But it's implicit and might be overly broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have scalable solution:

```js
type Base = {
  id: string;
  name: string;
}

type User = {
  tag: 'User'
} & Base

type Group = {
  tag: 'Group'
} & Base

type Expirience = {
  tag: 'Expirience'
} & Base

type Allowed = User | Group | Expirience

type MakeArray<T extends Base> = T extends Base ? T[] : T

type Result = MakeArray<Allowed>

class Foo<T extends Base> {
  add(entity: MakeArray<T>) {
  }
  remove(entity: MakeArray<T>) { }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAQghgZ2gXigbwFBSgSwCYBcUCwATjgHYDmA3FlBXALYREnnV0C%20GGokUAKpJSUVJmzA4VIgHJhEUrIxcoAMliIIvftADipAPYBXMGPT0pMqLIMmwy1RvhId4aAFEAHmBzkIFADGKBaS0nLevv5BEI7qmq587lAAggA2aYYA7hB45gqiAD5QdqZQxZF%20OAHBbgIAsnAA1hAppKRwIAA8ACpQEF7AAXgICRAAfOZ9A0MUI2NQAPxQPQDaALpQRD110ABKEAjGacDmjS1tHd3pmTl447yBaYijAGKGhr39g8OjLhOhKBwPB4AAUAWAOFARHOrXanV64wAlICeNhSBAmIYAG4QcEUSHQqCwy4InrI9BQHg8IA)

You can store all your allowed types/interfaces in `Allowed`.

`MakeArray` converts a union of elements to union of arrays of elements. In other words, applies `[]` to every element in the union. See [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types)

`Base` contains all required properties.

If tomorrow you will decide to add `Car` interface, just add it to `Allowed`